# How to remove this deadbolt?

Tags: doors, lock, deadbolt

I have an older deadbolt and instead of a faceplate or screws it looks to just have two “blanks”, and no visible way to remove it. Anybody familiar and know how to safely remove a bolt like this? It may be an antique…?

[image]

Adding some pics of the side.

I thought maybe the two circles were screw covers as well but I can’t seem to get them off, if that is what they are.

[image]

Comment: It just has covers on the screws. Pop them off with the smallest flat screwdriver you have. Like the kind from an eyeglass kit, that you're willing to possibly damage.

Comment: the pic with the two small circles is the inside side

Comment: @Mazura, I answered the same thing then deleted it. Post it as an answer. That is the way it is done. This may have been answered already